# NameError, variable is undefined

Tags: less

Today I'm start to learn Less and use this site https://lesstester.com/ to compile , and when I trying type this piece of code I have an error:

```
@var = "Some text";
@var1 = "var";

div:before {
 content: @@var1;
}
```

It might be replaced `@var1` to `@var`, but not working. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in Less should be assigned using `:`:

```
@var: "Some text";
@var1: "var";

div:before {
 content: @@var1;
}
```

More info: http://lesscss.org/#variables

Comment: On this stupid mistake  I spend too much time to figure out what I do wrong, thanks for help.